# Bigger NTC = better protection?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, thermistor, power-factor-correction, inrush-current

A 2.5 ohm NTC is used in the following PFC booster. I've got a 20 ohm one. Can I use it instead of 2.5ohm one? Does it provide better protection or does it disturb the normal operation of the circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bigger resistance NTC thermistor will reduce the inrush current on power up (its intended use)  but, it will also waste power when normally operating and, this may be completely undesirable. It may also cause the higher resistance NTC thermistor to overheat and fail.

The 2.5 ohm version is readily available in the UK: -

[image]

Hence, why risk using the wrong part when the right part is commonly available (at least in the UK).